# Using Powershell create folder and place file inside that folder according describe below condition

Tags: powershell-3.0

File named as 1.a First_DAY_Office.pdf

I want powershell script to write the file inside the folder as path :First/Day/1.a First_DAY_Office.pdf means I don't want file named to be changed only folder should be as above path.

I was able to get the result using file name and remove 1.a from file and then output is First/Day/First_DAY_Office.pdf .Please help me in this case

Answer (score 1):

## Base directory : Directory where your Input file is present

```
$dir_path='C:\Users\some-directory\'
```

## Input File name (for testing purpose i have used extension .txt instead of .pdf)

```
$input_file_name='1.a First_DAY_Office.txt'
```

## Get detail of file name with path

```
$input_file_name_with_path = $dir_path + $input_file_name
```

## Get Filename without extension

```
$File_Name=(Get-Item $input_file_name_with_path).Basename
```

## Split the String based on underscore('_') to get '1.a First' , 'DAY' and 'Office'

```
$1_a_first,$day,$office=$File_Name.split('_')
```

## Now split the string on space to get -> 1.a and First

```
$1_a,$first=$1_a_first.split('')
```

## Convert DAY to Day

```
$day_after_conversion = $day.substring(0,1).toupper()+ $day.substring(1).tolower()
```

## Next create new folder if not exist as per your requirement and then copy the file:

```
$folder_to_be_created = $first +'\'+ $day_after_conversion
$destination_path = $dir_path + $folder_to_be_created
If(!(test-path $path))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
      Copy-Item $input_file_name_with_path -Destination $destination_path

}
else
{
    Copy-Item $input_file_name_with_path -Destination $destination_path
}
```

Please let me know if it helped you.